# automating remote software installation

Tags: installation, remote, automation

I have a network consisting of n pcs(windows/linux).Now i want to automate installation on n pcs in netowrk.For example with one click of gtalk should get installed on n pc in network.Are there any softwares(paid/open src) that can be used to do this?One such software is IBM TPM but its dam expensive and complicated i guess.Are such software popular, cam asking this since i am planning to develop such software which is low priced.

Answer (score 0):

If your pcs are part of a Windows Active Directory domain you can publish the applications using Group Policy Objects that will give you that function for other Windows pcs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mixed environment I would recommend you look into OCS:
http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/

Not only does it do inventory but it does have the ability to do software deployment. I have never tried it myself, but I imagine it does work well.